# Code for finding the "longest" empty space in a grid

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I have written some code to find the longest line of empty space in a grid and I'd like to know if it can be simplified or shortened at all.

Here is an example of the input and output of the program:

#### Input

[image: Input]

#### Output

[image: Output]

As you can see, the program found the longest line to be near the top in the middle. The program is only looking for a 1 block wide line, which is by design. It also supports looking for the longest horizontal line too, which is not shown above.

#### Code

```js
function findLongestLineInRow(grid, position, direction) {
    let current = 0,
        start = 0,
        maximum = 0,
      offset = 0;

  const length = direction === 'vertical' ? grid.length : grid[0].length;

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const x = direction === 'vertical' ? position : i,
                y = direction === 'vertical' ? i : position;

    if (grid[y][x]) {
        if (current > maximum) {
        maximum = current;
        offset = start;
      }

        current = 0;
      start = i + 1;
    } else {
        current++;
    }
  }

  return {
    x: direction === 'vertical' ? position : offset,
    y: direction === 'vertical' ? offset : position,
    length: maximum,
    direction
  };
}

function findLongestLineInRowRange(start, end, direction) {
    let longest = { x: 0, y: 0, length: 0 };

  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
    const line = findLongestLineInRow(grid, i, direction);

    if (line.length > longest.length) {
            longest = line;
    }
  }

  return longest;
}

function findLongestLineInGrid(grid) {
    const horizontal = findLongestLineInRange(0, grid.length, 'horizontal'),
            vertical = findLongestLineInRange(0, grid[0].length, 'vertical');

  const { x, y, length, direction } = horizontal.length >= vertical.length ? horizontal : vertical;

  return {
    x, y,
    width: direction === 'vertical' ? 1 : length,
    height: direction ===  'vertical' ? length : 1,
  };
}
```

And here's an example of it running in the browser:

```js
function findLongestLineInRow(grid, position, direction) {
 let current = 0,
    start = 0,
    maximum = 0,
      offset = 0;
      
  const length = direction === 'vertical' ? grid.length : grid[0].length;
      
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   const x = direction === 'vertical' ? position : i,
       y = direction === 'vertical' ? i : position;
   
    if (grid[y][x]) {
     if (current > maximum) {
       maximum = current;
        offset = start;
      }
      
     current = 0;
      start = i + 1;
    } else {
     current++;
    }
  }
  
  return {
   x: direction === 'vertical' ? position : offset,
    y: direction === 'vertical' ? offset : position,
    length: maximum,
    direction
  };
}

function findLongestLineInRowRange(start, end, direction) {
 let longest = { x: 0, y: 0, length: 0 };
  
  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
   const line = findLongestLineInRow(grid, i, direction);
    
    if (line.length > longest.length) {
   longest = line;
    }
  }
  
  return longest;
}

function findLongestSpace(grid) {
 const horizontal = findLongestLineInRowRange(0, grid.length, 'horizontal'),
     vertical = findLongestLineInRowRange(0, grid[0].length, 'vertical');
        
  const { x, y, length, direction } = horizontal.length >= vertical.length ? horizontal : vertical;
  
  return {
   x, y,
   width: direction === 'vertical' ? 1 : length,
    height: direction ===  'vertical' ? length : 1,
  };
}

const generateRandomGrid = (width, height) =>
 Array(height).fill().map(() =>
   Array(width).fill().map(() => Math.random() < 0.5));
  
const drawGrid = (context, grid, cellSize) =>
 grid.forEach((column, y) =>
   column.forEach((cell, x) =>
     cell ? context.fillRect(x * cellSize, y * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize) : void 0));

const drawLongestSpace = (context, space, cellSize) => {
 context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75)';
  context.fillRect(space.x * cellSize, space.y * cellSize,
           space.width * cellSize, space.height * cellSize);
};

const context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
   grid = generateRandomGrid(50, 50),
      longestSpace = findLongestSpace(grid);
      
drawGrid(context, grid, 10);
drawLongestSpace(context, longestSpace, 10);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks pretty good. I'd probably prefer a `const VERTICAL = 'vertical'` to the repeated `'vertical'` string.

However, you could also add a function to transpose the grid, so columns become rows. I.e. instead of having each of your functions switch between vertical/horizontal all the time, simply transpose the input and output instead.